# How do i push new row during angular.forEach iteration?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, foreach, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have  service response as below and i want to push a new row in the response and bind the new row in my View. How do i do this with angular.forEach?

**Service Response**

```
"message":
{
   "student" [

     {
       "namee" : "student1", 
       "oDate" : "03/03/2016",
       "oTime" :  "5:00 PM"
     },
     {
       "namee" : "student2", 
       "oDate" : "03/03/2016",
       "oTime" :  "6:00 PM"
},{
       "namee" : "student3", 
       "oDate" : "03/03/2016",
       "oTime" :  "7:00 PM"
} ]        
     }

}     

angular.forEach(student, function(a))
{
var sessionDate = a.oDate + a.oTime;
this.push(sessionDate);
}
```

This push statement is not working for me. I am fine with to write it in a new array too. How do i acheive my requirement?

Comment: What is your outout??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, what you are trying to do is add session date to each 'object' within student.

Try

```
angular.forEach(student, function(a) {
    sessionDate = a.oDate + a.oTime;
    a.sessionDate = sessionDate;
});
```

Here is a plunkr with example http://plnkr.co/edit/MzdfefKbE3vZYnbt0Tm5?p=preview

Remember... push is for adding an object to an array.  In this case you are adding a key/value to a specific object within the array.

Comment: I edited it check my modified code.  Should work now

Comment: No problem! Just remember that push is for adding an object to an array.  In your case you are adding a key/value to an object within the array.